# Using VBA to find start value, count rows till that value becomes 0 and record result. Repeat for same column until the end of the data reached

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie to VBA/coding in general and my usual tactic of sticking bits of pre-written code isn't working for my problem.

I'm looking to create a macro that will do 3 things:

1. Allow me to find a starting point for the data in a column.
2. Start counting the number of rows once the cell value has
   changed to a constant.
3. Once the value moves back to the starting point for the count to stop and record the number of cells counted in separate column with positioning of the count in that column at the start point of the count.
4. Repeat until the end of the data.

For this case the start point will be when the cell has a value of >0. 
It will increase to a constant number (300). 
Once at 300 the macro will have to count the number of rows that contain the numerical value 300 until the value goes back to 0. 
Report count in a separate table on the worksheet with the entry being input at the same relative position in the new table as when the count started from the data. 
And finally the loop.

I need to also do a similar count but in the horizontal direction (i.e. counting columns on a row). If anyone can create a code for the vertical/row count problem above I'd really appreciate it if you could annotate it so I can attempt to understand/learn which bits of code carry out each action and thus change it up for horizontal/column count.

I've attached a screenshot of the spreadsheet however as a new user it must be as a link. The  blue highlighted table is the data used for the vertical /row count problem I am talking about. The blank table underneath the highlighted table has manually inputted correct answers for the first column of data for what I would like the macro to do in case I haven't accurately described my request.

I have also attached the horizontal table with correct manually inputted answers for row 1 in the separate table for the column count along the row.

Lastly, here is the code that I have written to tackle the problem, however it is very basic and won't run.

```
Sub  Count0()
  For Each c In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D30:D39")
     If c.Value = 0 Then
     End If
     If c.Value > 0 Then
       v = Range(c.Value)
       For i = 3 To Rows.Count
         If Cells(i, 1).Value <> v Then
           MsgBox CStr(i - 2)
         End If         
       Next i

  Next c
End Sub
```

[image: Row count along column]

[image: Column count along row]

Comment: Real quick, add `Dim c as Range` before the `For` loop, then change the `If` to `If c.Value = "0" Then `... and see if that helps.  Also, you don't need `If c.Value = 0 Then End If`, since your next line checks if it's larger than 0.  Also, step through the macro with `F8` and see if you can see why/when it skips the loop completely.  I assume it's just not running, or does it throw an error?

Comment: Please add an Excel sample and it will most probably be solved by the community

Comment: Also, by using a standard indent...you can see that you are missing an `End If`  And you can simply remove `If c.Value = 0 Then End If` as it does nothing

Answer (score 1):

This worked in the limited case I tested (two columns and several rows in different patterns. It's pretty basic--there are more elegant ways to do it.

```
Sub Count0()

'To hold the current cell
Dim current As Range

'To hold the total number of rows and columns having data
Dim rows As Long
Dim cols As Long

'To iterate across rows and columns
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

'Flag/counter variables
Dim found As Long       'Saves row on which first "constant" was found
Dim count As Long       'Saves count of "contants"

'Use SpecialCells method to obtain the maximum number of rows and columns
' that have data.
cols = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
rows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Increment through all columns that have data. This is a bit inefficient
' because it really isn't necessary to go through all the empty cells,
' but it works.
For c = 1 To cols

    'Initialize flag/counter
    found = 0
    count = 0

    'Increment through all rows for the current column.
    For r = 1 To rows

        'Examine the current cell
        Set current = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, c)

        'For positive values, save the first row that has the value
        ' and count the number of values.
        If current.Value > 0 Then
            If found = 0 Then found = r
            count = count + 1
        End If

        'When the next non-positive value is reached--OR the end of the
        ' row is reached--and there was a constant found, write the count
        ' to the next worksheet in the cell corresponding to the row and
        ' column having the first instance of the constant.
        If (current.Value <= 0 Or r = rows) And found > 0 Then

            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(found, c).Value = count

            'Reset the flag/counter
            found = 0
            count = 0

        End If
    Next r
Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with what you had written, and ended up doing this in the end.  I left you variables for changing the sheets to read from and print to (assuming you can print the results to another sheet- if not it should be easy enough to change).

This should also work for all cells in your range, assuming that there are values in all boxes.

Problems I noted with your original code were:

1. The first `if` did nothing
2. I'm pretty sure you shouldn't use numbers in sub/function names
3. Dimensioning no variables is a bad idea

Anyway, give me a comment if you need any help (and well done for writing a good first question).

```
Sub CountZero()
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet, SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentCell As Range
    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim FirstColumn As Long, LastColumn As Long
    Dim TotalValues As Long

    Set SourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set SummarySheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    FirstRow = 1
    LastRow = SourceSheet.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row

    FirstColumn = 1
    LastColumn = SourceSheet.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column

    For col = FirstColumn To LastColumn
        For Rw = FirstRow To LastRow

            Set CurrentCell = SourceSheet.Cells(Rw, col)

            If CurrentCell <> 0 Then
                TotalValues = ProcessSection(CurrentCell)
                SummarySheet.Cells(Rw, col).value = TotalValues
                Rw = Rw + TotalValues
            End If

        Next Rw
    Next col
End Sub


Function ProcessSection(FirstCellWithValue As Range) As Long
    Dim Counter As Long: Counter = 0
    Do Until FirstCellWithValue.Offset(Counter, 0).value <> FirstCellWithValue.value
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop
    ProcessSection = Counter
End Function
```

As a small disclaimer, I haven't tested this, let me know if there are problems.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the response.
So the code is sort of working. When it records the data it does so in the correct relative cell however it sometimes misses values and I would like it to record the data on the same sheet. 

As the spreadsheet is a little busy and as I can't really decipher your code (complete newbie sorry) I am uploading a slimmed down version of the excel which may help you write the code.

Any help is much appreciated.